# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when trying to create object via constructor

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to learn swift and the concept of optionals is destroying me.

I have the code below and it keeps crashing when trying to create an Event object b/c eventDescription is finding a nil value. How can I get past this error and create my Event object with a description that is either nil or an empty string?

```
EventDao.getUpcoming() {
                (upcomingEvents, error) -> Void in

                if(upcomingEvents != nil) {

                    // Loop through all the events
                    for currentEvent in upcomingEvents! {

print(currentEvent)

                        let name = currentEvent["name"] as! NSString
                        let start = currentEvent["start"] as! NSString
                        let teamId = currentEvent["team_id"] as! Int
                        let eventDescription = currentEvent["description"] as? String
                        let eventId = currentEvent["id"] as! Int

                        // Format date format
                        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start as String)
                        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
                        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
                        let formattedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)


                        self.getTeamInfo(teamId) {
                            (team, err) -> Void in

                            self.getMyResponseForEvent(eventId) {
                                (response, err) -> Void in

                                print(eventDescription)

                                var event: Event

                                if (response == nil) {
                                    event = Event(name: name as String, team: team!, time: formattedDate, description: eventDescription! as! String, myResponse: "No Response") // ERRORS HERE WITH: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                                } else {
...
```

`print(currentEvent` outputs:

```
{
    "default_response" =     {
        id = 1;
        label = "No Response";
    };
    description = "<null>";
    end = "2016-01-19T19:00:43.000-06:00";
    id = 1966;
    location = Withers;
    name = "Game 5 VS cat.png";
    start = "2016-01-19T18:00:43.000-06:00";
    "team_id" = 193;
    timezone = "America/Chicago";
}
```

This is my Event.swift file:

```
import Foundation

class Event {

    // MARK: Properties

    var name: String
    var team: Team
    var time: String
    var description: String?
    var myResponse: String

    // MARK: Initialization

    init(name: String, team: Team, time: String, description: String, myResponse: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.time = time
        self.description = description
        self.myResponse = myResponse
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't force unwrap your variables with `!`. Use `if-let` or `guard` to unwrap them. One of your optionals is `nil` somewhere, but it's hard to say where, exactly, because there are `!`s all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if let t = team where response == nil {
    event = Event(name: name as String, team: t, time: formattedDate, description: eventDescription ?? "", myResponse: "No Response") 
} else...
```

One of your optionals was `nil`. Either `team!` was `nil`, or `eventDescription!` was `nil`. You can use the "nil coalescing operator" `??` to try to unwrap `eventDescription` and substitute a blank string if it is `nil`.

BTW, you shouldn't need to conditionally cast `eventDescription` to `String` again, since you already did that when you created it, in this line:

```
let eventDescription = currentEvent["description"] as? String
```

At that point, it is either a `String` or it is `nil`. You don't need to cast it again.

Just about every time you see the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` it is because you are force unwrapping an optional with `!`.

Comment: I will try this out. i know for a fact that eventDescription is nil, but I want a blank value when creating an Event object.

Comment: It needs to be `desription: eventDescription ?? ""`, not `description: eventDescription??`. Although, if you know for a fact that `eventDescription` is `nil`, why do you include it at all? Why not just pass an empty `String`? As in: `description: ""`

Comment: I just know for this one case where it's erroring out. Sometimes it does have a value.

Comment: In that case you do want to use `desription: eventDescription ?? ""`. You can read more about the "`nil` coalescing operator" (`??`) [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3ru60t6rKAhXIXB4KHfyVCfgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FSwift%2FConceptual%2FSwift_Programming_Language%2FBasicOperators.html&usg=AFQjCNG2m9UH7bRGS6Rk-GVavujJuT0LGw&sig2=akLDAerfnIYrpvsJj3pwtA&bvm=bv.111677986,d.dmo).